# find 1 way liked friends out of two tables(relation) named as mutual friends and likes.SQL, DATABASE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, social-networking

two tables are named as likes and other as friends.
both contain two columns.1st column contain ID numbers of users against their mutual friends in 2nd column.
i just want to know the query that is
delete that rows from likes tables which contain friends that are mutual friends and only 1 way liking is done..which means 1 of the mutual friend has liked not the other. this information is given in likes table.
two columns. 1 contain id of user who liked the other which is present in 2nd column.

friends table

```
id 1     id 2                                  
11        22-                                      
22        11-                                 
33        77*                                 
55        68                                                                    
77        33*

68        55
```

likes

```
id 1     id 2                                  
11          22   (should be DELETED)                                     
22          11   (should be DELETED)                                 
33          77   (should be DELETED)                                 
55          68    (save it)                                                                   
77          33   (should be DELETED)
```

Comment: You have tagged this question both [tag:mysql] and [tag:oracle].  Which RDBMS are you using?  Whilst both are products owned by The Oracle Corporation, they are in fact very different (the former is free and open-source; whilst the latter is commercial and proprietary closed-source).  It is important because their SQL variants have different syntaxes.

Comment: 55 is friends with 68 and 55 likes 68, according to the explained logics and examples, why is it "(save it)" on the 2nd table?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the results of a join:

```
DELETE l1 FROM likes l1 JOIN likes l2 ON l1.id1 = l2.id2 AND l1.id2 = l1.id1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete id where id in select friends inner join   id1 to id2 and Id2 to ID1

```
delete from likes where F1.id1 in (
  select f1.*,f2.* 
     from freinds f1 
    inner join freinds f2 on 
    F1.id1 = F2.id2  and F1.id2=F2.id1
   )
```

Comment: i didnot understood it much. could you explain the concept not the code just the concept ????

Comment: @AtirChaudary I understand than you want to deleted in likes table where the friends are in friends of it
also inner join allow to find it to linked friends_1.id2 to Friends_2.id1 and friends_1.id1 to Friends_2.id2.
for the delete where clause cheked if id1 is in Select statement

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this case is as follows:
I concat id1 and id2 as a string, then I compare it to the concatenation from the second table and remove matching entries.

```
DELETE FROM likes
WHERE CONCAT(id1, '-',id2) IN (SELECT concat(id1,'-',id2) AS Relationship FROM friends);
```

for example, if there is a likes '11-22' and there is a friends '11-22' then, that 'like' entry should be removed, is it? Well that's how this approach works.